# rewrite URL to simulate a different path?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got no experience with URL rewriting so apologies if this is widely covered.

I have an ugly URL path that I want to improve using mod_rewrite or any viable alternative.

**www.domain.com/temp/user/**

Is it possible to make this appear as

**www.domain.com/user/**

without moving folders & files around?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) !^/temp
RewriteRule ^(.*) /temp/$1 [L]
```

rewrites everything, that is not a real file, to `/temp`

Comment: oops, I didn't mention that user is the actual folder name for the user so it will be a variable and will always be different depending on which user you're trying to access. How can you cater for that in htaccess ?

Comment: The code above should do just that. Did you notice the is no `user` present in the code? @rodneyrehm the leading slash shouldn't be there in htaccess. So use just `RewriteRule ^(.*) /temp/$1 [L]`. Also if the file also doesn't exist in /temp you'll get a infinite redirect. `/notexist` redirect to `/temp/notexist`, which redirect to `/temp/temp/notexist`, etc. Add `RewriteCond $1 !^temp/`.

Comment: the second RewriteCond should take care of that loop now

Comment: The redirect seems to work okay for mysite.com/user but it gives me a 500 internal server error if it's mysite.com/user/ How can I cater for that trailing slash as well? Thanks!